# Ng-submit called twice with Routeprovider

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I use the same `form` to create and update users in database. I can update properly, but when I create one user, submit send twice and create two same users in database.

I have this in `RouteProvider`.

```
 .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/users", {
                controller: "MainControlador",
                templateUrl: "templates/users.html"
            })
            .when("/user/:id", {
                controller: "UserControlador",
                templateUrl: "templates/user.html"
            })
            .when("/users/edit/:id", {
                controller: "UserControlador",
                templateUrl: "templates/form.html"
            })
            .when("/users/new", {
                controller: "NewUserControlador",
                templateUrl: "templates/form.html"
            })
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "templates/main.html"
            })
            .otherwise("/");
    })
```

This is my `form`

```
<div>
      <form ng-submit="saveUser()">
        <input ng-model="user.name" type="text" required>
        <input ng-model="user.surname" type="text" required>
        <input ng-model="user.phone" type="text"required>
        <input ng-model="user.email"type="text" required>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
 </div>
```

And finally i use this `controller`

```
//Controller Update
.controller("UserControlador", function($scope, $routeParams, UserAPI) {
        $scope.title = "Edit user";

        UserAPI.getOne($routeParams.id).success(function(data) {
            //Get Array First Element
            $scope.user = data[0];
        })

        $scope.saveUser = function() {
            var data = ({
                id: $routeParams.id,
                name: $scope.user.name,
                surname: $scope.user.surname,
                phone: $scope.user.phone,
                email: $scope.user.email
            });
            UserAPI.update(data).success(function(data) {
                $scope.user = data;
            })
        }

    })
    //Controller Create
    .controller("NewUserControlador", function($scope, UserAPI) {
        $scope.title = "Add user";
        $scope.saveUser = function() {
            var data = ({
                name: $scope.user.name,
                surname: $scope.user.surname,
                phone: $scope.user.phone,
                email: $scope.user.email,
            });
            UserAPI.create(data).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.user = data;
            })
        }
    })
```

¿Any idea what happen here? I tried to use console.log but apparently all works fine. I tried to use too Angular batarang to debug angular calls but don´t work.

Comment: Could you provide your submit input ?

Comment: Submit return correct values. Maybe errors are in function calls.

Comment: I don't see any button inside `form` tag which is responsible for submitting form

Comment: Can you create a reproducible problem on Plunker?

Comment: ng-submit works like a submit button, see here http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-submit.asp

Comment: There's got to be a <input type="submit"> or button for that to work

Comment: I add button and still adding two same users when i create one user.

Comment: ¿I can repeat same url template in different controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very stupid error. In my PHP code I have this...

```
<?php
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=httpcrud;charset=utf8", "root", "");
$userName = $_GET['userName'];
$userSurname = $_GET['userSurname'];
$userPhone = $_GET['userPhone'];
$userEmail = $_GET['userEmail'];
$sql=$conexion->query("INSERT INTO users (name,surname,phone,email) VALUES('$userName','$userSurname','$userPhone','$userEmail')");
$json = json_encode($sql->execute());
echo $json;
?>
```

The submit repeat `insert`  when I use `$sql->execute()`  and  `query()`  . I delete  `$json= json_encode($sql->execute());` to `$json = json_encode($sql)` and finally all works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared two controllers, one for saving the user (*NewUserControlador*) and one for updating *(UserControlador)*. Both methods are called saveUser() and they are declared on the $scope.

There might be a conflict because of the same name.
Why don't you use one Controller for those operations? They are all CRUD operations for the same Entity (User) after all.

If you still want to use two different controllers, you could use some logging to find out what is happening or a greater idea would be to rename the update method in the UserControlador.

More information about scopes can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: If i put create and update functions in same controllers, the same errors occurs, create two same users in database >-<